# AppStore Update Policy

Tags: macos, app-store

Just wondering what will happen if the current app version supports OS 10.6.6 upwards and you upload a version that is built for Lion.

Will the 10.6 users be still able to download the version that is for 10.6 or will they be forced to upgrade to 10.7? My guess is the latter, but I'm not 100% sure.

How would you handle the jump from 10.6 to 10.7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple's storefront database knows which version of OS X your app currently requires (the Deployment Target), and thus might not allow the App Store application on your Mac to update an app if the Mac on which the App Store application is running does not have a proper OS version for that app.

Comment: Yes, but if someone uninstalls the App and want's to install it again some point later they are screwed, right?

Comment: @Erik - If they don't have a backup (Time Machine, et.al.).  Similar to previous versions of iTunes music.  Caveat Emptor.

Answer (score 0):

Any update ***replaces*** the previous version. If the new version you plan to release requires 10.7, then I strongly encourage you to disclose that information in the update so that users who plan not to upgrade right away will know not to install your update.

Comment: Well, in my experience people mostly don't read update texts at all, so I guess I'm stuck with supporting Snow Leopard (just wanted to avoid the multi OS install on a 128GB SSD MBP).